# GFCI - Open Neutral on newer one versus Open Ground on older one

Tags: gfci

Background: We are having extensive home renovations done.
The kitchen has been remodeled with new GFCI outlets installed. 
[image: Updated GFCI outlet]A Prime Products Polarity Check device indicates there is correct polarity.  When the outlet is tested the Polarity Check indicates an Open Ground.  When I test the outlet with a voltmeter there is little  voltage (less than 1 volt) between the hot and neutral or the hot and ground, which I think is correct since I'm using a high impedance voltmeter.

Here's what I'm trying to understand: During the last couple of  weeks the outside  contractors had a couple of compressors running, one from the outlet in my garage and another from the back of the house.  They lost power on both but no circuit breakers were tripped.  The GFCI outlet in the bathroom that has not been remodeled (house was built in the mid-1980s) was tripped.  I have attached a picture of that one.   [image: Bathroom GFCI outlet installed when the house was built]When I reset it, power was restored to the outlets I mentioned.  However when I tested it while the power was lost, the polarity check indicated and Open Ground (no lights).  I didn't think too much of it then.  I didn't test it with a voltmeter then.

I just went back to look further into  the bathroom GFCI outlet's behavior.  **After I push the Test button I measure little or no voltage between the hot and neutral.  However there was 120 volts between hot and ground.**
**Does this make sense?**

It seems to me that a GFCI outlet should disconnect power when a ground fault is sensed.
Please let me know what you think about this.
Thanks in advance.
Jim

Comment: Oh, those 3-light testers are a disaster.  The lights are useful, but there's always a sticker with extremely misleading indications of what the lights mean.  [This one would be more accurate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEx9e.png).

Comment: I'll look into the tester.  However my question was more basic.  I apologize for not being clearer.   After I press the Test button on the kitchen GFCI outlet (first pic.) there is essentially no voltage drop (less than 1 V) between the hot and ground or hot and neutral.     **After I press the Test button on the older GFCI outlet (second pic.) there is essentially no voltage drop between hot and neutral but there is a 120 V drop between hot and ground.**  I measured the voltage with a voltmeter. **Should I see a 120 volt drop between hot and ground  in the test condition?**

Comment: No, a GFCI should be dead as a stone after it trips.  The same for anything downline of the GFCI.  Sounds like that one has gone bad.

Comment: I agree with harpers comment but I have read phantom voltages on solid state electronics that showed 120v with a high impedance meter but 0v with a low z meter ( the leakage was in the micro amp level “ safe”).

Comment: Thanks Harper - Reinstate Monica. That's what I thought.

Comment: Ed Beal:   I'll check it with a lower impedance analog meter.  Thanks.